# jQuery Mobile Tap/click spans across pages

Tags: forms, listview, jquery-mobile, onclick, click

I experienced a problem with jQuery Mobile's click event.

When I clicked on a list item on my list view to transit from the first page to the second page, I noticed that the form element on the second page was selected.

After repeated tries, I concluded that the form element (dropdown list) was "focused" because it was "clicked" on.

Simply put, the region which I clicked on the first page "took effect" on the form element on the second page.

I have tried to do a search on the internet, it seems that no one is experiencing what I'm encountering.

I appreciate any advice given.

[Update] I am developing for iPhone with iOS 5.0 using jQuery Mobile 1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

There's at least [one open issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2248) on jQuery Mobile's GitHub page that matches your description so it might just be a bug in jQuery Mobile. You could comment there (and here too) what jQuery Mobile version and what device you are using.

Comment: Thanks Oiva. I am using jQuery Mobile 1.0.1, developing for iPhone with iOS 5.0. The posting on GitHub says that there are no issues for iOS. On a side note, I tried upgrading to jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC 1 and it did solve the problem. However, I reverted to jQM 1.0.1 since jQM 1.1.0 seems to have quite a number of unresolved issues. Does anyone have any workarounds to this problem?